# How to troubleshoot Xss vulnerability in Node.js and socket.io-based chat

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm developing a simple chat application based on node.js and socket.io. There is an XSS vulnerability. How can I filter HTML codes in input data entries?

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    socket.emit('chat', {   
        message: message.value,
        kullanıcıadı: kullanıcıadı.value
    });
```

Comment: You could set the message like `element.textContent = 'user message<b>asd</b>';`. This way the message is not executed.

Comment: striptags or sanitize-html npm package might help.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862271/socket-io-sanitize-incoming-data-xss